# how to have multiple radio buttons for a single item in xhtml

Tags: xhtml, radio-button

I'm building an xhtml where I will have about 3 images, and I want each image to have 2 radio buttons with the letters A and B , which will mean A "most beautiful" and B "most dynamic", so the users can pic image1 to be A & B, or pic image2 as A and image3 as B, or image1 as B and image3 as A or any otehr permutation of such.

how can I accomplish this? I haven't found any tutorials online or anything. is there a simple way to group them? so ony one 'A' can be selected across the images and only one "B" can be selected. because I'd rather not use javascript to emulate a radiobutton across the images.

```
<table width="100%" border="1">
                <h:selectOneRadio id="oppelonas"
                    value="#{historialAndrogeneticoBB.images}">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <table  border="1">
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="A" itemValue="2A" />
                                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="B" itemValue="2B" />
                                 </td>
                                <td>
                                    <img src="/image1.png" alt="2" />
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            </table>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <table  border="1">>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="A" itemValue="3VA" /> 
                                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="B" itemValue="3VB" />
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <img src="/image2" alt="3V" />
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            </table>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <table  border="1">>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <f:selectItem itemLabel="A" itemValue="5AA" /> 
                                        <f:selectItem itemLabel="B" itemValue="5AB" />
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <img src="/image3" alt="5A" />
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                </h:selectOneRadio>
            </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

they must have the same name attribute   like a group of buttons 
ok i have done this small code

```
> <div>     <input type="radio" value="A" class="ClassA" />     
> <input type="radio" value="b" class="ClassB" /> </div> <div>  
> <input type="radio" value="A" class="ClassA" />   
> <input type="radio"  value="b" class="ClassB" /> <div>
>
```

> var
>   el=document.getElementsByClassName("ClassA"); 
>   if(el[0].checked) {
>     el[1].checked=false;  // here u can add some loop to uncheck the rest of elements 
>   }

u must add the event handler to it to get the concerned element i lieu of special item number 
i hope that it's close to what u want to do

Comment: what do you mean the same name attribute? can you examplify?

Comment: Please give an example to clarify your answer.